# In ArrayList of ArrayList, How should I retain values in parent arraylist while updating the inner one?

Tags: java, arraylist, memory-management, collections

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> aal=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> al= new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=2;i<6;i++)
{
    al.add(i);
    if(i%2!=0)
    {
        aal.add(al);
        al.clear();
    }
}
```

Output: [[4,5][4,5]]

**Required output: [[2,3][4,5]]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`al.clear()` will also clear the contents of the array list that you have just put into `aal`. This is because the array list in `aal` and the one referenced by `al` are the *same* array list. Here are two ways you can fix this.

1. Create a new array list after adding to `aal`:

   ```
   for(int i=2;i<6;i++)
   {
       al.add(i);
       if(i%2!=0)
       {
           aal.add(al);
           al = new ArrayList<>();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add a copy of `al` to `aal` (this is probably what you expected your code would do):

   ```
   for(int i=2;i<6;i++)
   {
       al.add(i);
       if(i%2!=0)
       {
           aal.add(new ArrayList<>(al));
           al.clear();
       }
   }
   ```

Notice in both of these cases, I am creating new array lists with `new ArrayList<>`.

Comment: Thanks alot... It's working